# Search and replace only specific lines in R

Tags: r, search, replace

I would like to search and replace in my database some characters but not in all the lines.

Here's my data base :

```
 1. 41 R JEAN JAURES 93170
 2. 42 AV DE STALINGRAD 93170
 3. 51 57 R JULES FERRY 93170
 4. 1 R DU HAVRE 93170
```

I would like to replace to have :

```
 5. 41 RUE JEAN JAURES 93170
 6. 42 AVENUE DE STALINGRAD 93170
 7. 51 57 RUE JULES FERRY 93170
 8. 1 RUE DU HAVRE 93170
```

So, I try the `sub()` function, but in `2.` it will replace the first `R` so it will be STALING**RUE**AD instead of STALING**R**AD.

I also try the `substr()` but like in 3. there might be some long number of character before the letter to replace. As I have ~600k addresses there will be lot of exceptions like this.

Is there a way to add some restrictions in those functions to fulfill my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\\s+` to match 1 or more spaces and `\\s*` to match 0 or more spaces.

```
 vec <- c("41 R JEAN JAURES 93170",
 "42 AV DE STALINGRAD 93170",
 "51 57 R JULES FERRY 93170",
 "1 R DU HAVRE 93170")


 library(magrittr)
 vec %>% 
   gsub("\\s*R\\s+", " RUE ", .) %>%
   gsub("\\s*AV\\s+", " AVENUE ", .)

[1] "41 RUE JEAN JAURES 93170"      "42 AVENUE DE STALINGRAD 93170"
[3] "51 57 RUE JULES FERRY 93170"   "1 RUE DU HAVRE 93170"
```

Furthermore you might consider `\\b` for word boundaries (which includes space):

```
 vec %>% 
   gsub("\\bR\\s+", "RUE ", .) %>%
   gsub("\\bAV\\s+", "AVENUE ", .)
```

Comment: or use `\\b` on both sides

Comment: Note that I would use `\\s` instead of `\\s+` (or even `\b` which would be the best solution)

Comment: Agree.  I thought in the moment was that using `\\s+` would be nice to clean up inconsistencies but that is probably best done in a separate step.

Answer (score -1):

You can try some regular expressions with `stringr`. If 'R' for 'RUE' will consistently be the first 'R' character in each line, you could use `stringr::str_replace`, which replaces only the first match in each string:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.5.1
data <- c(
  "1. 41 R JEAN JAURES 93170",
  "2. 42 AV DE STALINGRAD 93170",
  "3. 51 57 R JULES FERRY 93170",
  "4. 1 R DU HAVRE 93170")
data %>% 
  str_replace("(?<!\\w)R(?!\\w)", "RUE")
#> [1] "1. 41 RUE JEAN JAURES 93170"    "2. 42 AV DE STALINGRAD 93170"
#> [3] "3. 51 57 RUE JULES FERRY 93170" "4. 1 RUE DU HAVRE 93170"
```

Edit: added a second reprex after the "R" per the comments

Comment: `STALINGRUEAD` issues still present

Comment: lmao you're right. Copied the wrong code. Edited with the right regex!

Comment: What about `42 R DE REAUMUR` ? it'll become `42 RUE DE RUEEAUMUR`

Comment: Added a second regex

Comment: Which is now almost equivalent to `\\bR\\b`

Comment: @RHertel hadn't noticed that. Thanks! Just updated R