# Search and replace using R

Tags: r, search, replace

I have posted a question about searching and replacing some specific characters ([Search and replace only specific lines in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540961/search-and-replace-only-specific-lines-in-r#51541413)). But there are some specific lines that I didn't take into account and the answers are not fully adapted.
Let's retake my data (adding line 5 and 6):

```
 1. 41 R JEAN JAURES 93170
 2. 42 AV DE STALINGRAD 93170
 3. 51 57 R JULES FERRY 93170
 4. 1 R DU HAVRE 93170
 5. 100B R DU HAVRE 93179
 6. 100 AV DU BAOBAB 98030
```

I want to have :

```
 1. 41 RUE JEAN JAURES 93170
 2. 42 AVENUE DE STALINGRAD 93170
 3. 51 57 RUE JULES FERRY 93170
 4. 1 RUE DU HAVRE 93170
 5. 100 ***BIS*** RUE DU HAVRE 93179
 6. 100 AVENUE DU BAOBAB 98030
```

The answer was to use \b to make some boundary, e.g. `sub("\\bAV\\b", " AVENUE ", base)`. But for the 100B, if I use `sub("B\\b"," BIS ", base)` it will also take all the words finishing by B. For example in the 6. it will make BAOBA B.

Is there a way to say if it's a number before B change to BIS, but if it's letters don't. (obviously my lines are character variables)

Comment: Use a positive look behind assertion : `(?<=\\d)B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this by specifying *digits* with `\\d`

```
sub("\\b(\\d+)B", "\\1 BIS ", base)
```

Also, you might consider using `gsub` instead of `sub` if this might occur more than once in a single address.

**Data**

Here is some sample data based on data in the question.

```
base = c('41 R JEAN JAURES 93170',
'42 AV DE STALINGRAD 93170',
'51 57 R JULES FERRY 93170',
'1 R DU HAVRE 93170',
'100B R DU HAVRE 93179',
'100 AV DU BAOBAB 98030')
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Will add to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [PCRE regex backend](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html)    you can use positive and negative lookahead assertions. For example, here you are saying the `B` must be preceded by a digit for a match to occur.

```
sub("(?<=\\d)B\\b", "BIS", base, perl=TRUE)
```